# Communicate two view models in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am developing a WPF application and I have some problems to communicate one view model with another.

I have:

1. MainViewModel
2. ChildViewModel1
3. ChildViewModel2

Every time a property changes in MainViewModel, ChildViewModel1 and ChildViewModel2 should get notified.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?

EDIT:
I am thinking in a solution descrided MVVM Light (http://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/23821#313594.), that is implementing a message bus. Is it the right approach?

Comment: Way too general. You need to try this on your own. See [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Comment: The title of this is misleading and there's not a specific question.

Comment: I don't know about other MVVM frameworks, but MVVM Light and ReactiveUI include messages bus implementations as mentioned in your title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the common way for viewmodels to communicate between themselves
 is implimentation of theMediator design pattern

here is how it is done in MVVMLight
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/27aaefff-e463-451c-87d9-37367a343e0e

in Prism is:
http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2011/01/15/Using-the-Prism-40-Event-Aggregator.aspx

in Caliburn is:
http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/01/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/

Comment: two links related:
1)http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35277/MVVM-Mediator-Pattern
2)http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/a-mediator-prototype-for-wpf-apps/

Comment: @guilhermecgs , both links are broken to me

Comment: @Геннадий Ванин Новосибирск, both links are working for me. Are you sure you are not under a firewall?

Comment: @guilhermecgs  , started to work for me too

Comment: The way the answer is written seems to suggest that the mediator pattern and the event aggregator pattern are the same thing, but they're not: https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/03/18/event-aggregator-andorvs-mediator-a-tale-of-two-patterns.

Answer (score 12):

In most cases I would NOT suggest using any centralized place to share "events"/"notifications", like EventAggregator, etc.. This leads to later issues related with not clear relations between ViewModels. Such notifications makes sense in very specific cases when relations between listener/publisher is not known even on design stage.
I would suggest draw simple diagram with relations between ViewModels and find a way of using standard .NET events, so when you have clear realtionships between ViewModels like ViewModel1 has a reference to ViewModel2 so can subscribe to an event or provide own callback, so it will be easy to build such event notifications.

Comment: it is a good answer, but since my application is very simple, I will use a "centralized place to share "events"/"notifications", like EventAggregator" due to plenty of references and code examples

Comment: this is a very bad advice that would lead to horrible memory leaks very quickly.
if you want to see relations more clearly you can create a resharper addon that will recongnize register/unsubscribe patterns

Comment: This approach is much easier to debug than the accepted answer.

Comment: Could you provide a very simple example of what you suggested? I need very simple thing to pass an object from one view model to the other. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a IService that is implemented by each view model.  Then in the view models you can pass the service properties to properties of the view model that implement INotifypropertychanged.  For example, I have a service called INavigationService that is implemented by my view models and it has properties like CanNavigate, currentView etc that I bind to in my view models.  Changes to these properties can cause navigation or change properties that other view models are binding to.

Comment: Could you provide a very simple example of what you suggested? I need very simple thing to pass an object from one view model to the other. Can you help me?